# build new array of object using map of es2015

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have a set of data, I want to build a new one with custom property name, the existing set of data has nested, that's also one of the reason why I need to normalize it to suite my own use.

says I have this existing set of data

```
[{
name:"abc",
company:{name:"abc company",age_of_company:1},
age: 19
}]
```

I want to build a new array of object where the property and nested level will be like this

```
[{
ceo_name:"abc",
company_name:"abc company",
age: 19
}]
```

I'm stuck

```
const newData = existingData.map(obj => (
//obj.company.name I don't know what to do here
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const newData = existingData.map(obj => (
    {
        ceo_name: obj.name,
        company_name: obj.company.name,
        age: obj.age
    }
))
```

Comment: you don't need a return?

Comment: The arrow notation automatically returns the value

Comment: To be precise, the **compact body** form of the arrow function automatically returns the value (the form without `{}`).

Answer (score 1):

You can destructure the parameters of the function passed to `map` as follows:

```
existingData.map(
  ({age, name: ceo_name, company: {name: company_name}}) =>
    ({ceo_name, company_name, age}))
```

Comment: how about the undefined value? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601425/map-return-undefined-array-of-object

Comment: @GialaJefferson What are you worried about being undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[{
    name:"abc",
    company:{name:"abc company",age_of_company:1},
    age: 19
}].map(element => {
    return {
        ceo_name: element.name,
        company_name: element.company.name,
        age: element.age
    }
})
```

Comment: worked, great, but I have another problem now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601425/map-return-undefined-array-of-object

Answer (score 0):

```
const newData = existingData.map(obj => {
  const { name, company, age } = obj;
    return {
      ceo_name: name,
      company_name: company.name,
      age: age
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: is const needed here?

Comment: Second line destructures the object so you can avoid repeatedly referencing `obj`. 

`obj.name` becomes `name`, etc.