# map return undefined array of object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const newDate = map(items.result, (obj => {
  if (isDateWithinRage(obj.date_from)) {
    return {
      "date": obj.join_date,
      "name": obj.student.name
    }
  }
}))
```

The if statement has produced something like this

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, Object, Object, Object]
```

How to fix the undefined part? I want to skip the iteration.

Comment: I think you are looking for filter https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `map` is some variant of [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), `map` produces a 1:1 mapping of values from your input array to an output array.

When you want to exclude values from your input array, use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
const newDate =
  items
    .result
    .filter(obj => isDateWithinRange(obj.date_from))
    .map(obj => ({
      date: obj.join_date,
      name: obj.student.name
    }));
```

<sub>This example assumes that `items.result` is an Array</sub>